# Is this sentence badly structured

Tags: grammar

People usually shrug at the notion of an interviewer influencing and guiding the interviewee towards the answer they want.

Is there a better way to write this sentence. And is there a better word to use other than shrug. I tried 'do not tolerate' but that sounds harsh.

Comment: Merriam Webster defines **shrug** - *"to raise and lower your shoulders usually to show that you do not know or care about something"* ...........if you mean "disappointed but expect" then use those words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That an interviewer would guide, even (subtly) direct, an interviewee to a pre-determined response is frowned upon.

...this captures your essence, adds a nuance, but do you want a stronger expression of disapproval?